# What Load Test tools are available that can consume AWS ALB logs from S3

Tags: load-testing

Are there any recommended Load Test tools / services that are able to cycle through AWS Application Load Balancer logs stored in S3 preferably utilising the time stamps to perform piano roll type functionality?

Answer (score 1):

[aws-log-replay](https://github.com/mapbox/aws-log-replay) seems to be something you're looking for, it can replay requests with defined concurrency.

---

With regards to more or less popular load testing tools I can only think of Apache JMeter with [Access Log Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) which support out of box access log files from Tomcat, Weblogic, Reisin and SunOne, however you can come up with your own implementation of [Generator](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/Generator.java) class or dynamically populate [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler fields using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) like it's described in [Stop Making Assumptions! Learn How to Replay Your Production Traffic With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/stop-making-assumptions-learn-how-replay-your-production-traffic-jmeter) guide.

---

Actually I don't think you will be able to produce realistic load by replaying your access logs, it might work for something simple like static content, however if your application assumes authentication, sessions, complex workflows, etc. - I'm afraid your "replay" attempt will got stuck at login page.

So instead of trying to replay complex scenarios from the logs I would suggest sticking to the load testing tool of your choice and create it from scratch. Access logs can be used to identify workload distribution (like X % of users are normally doing this, Y % are doing that, etc.) and anticipated concurrency (like at X time we had Y online users).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Yes it is the case that it will be used for something simple like static content - so the issues you rightly highlighted are fortunately not applicable. Cheers.